# Android BLE Scanner Permissions Exception

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, scanning

I'm, having trouble getting scan results back from the BLE scanner.  I have the proper permissions (ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) in my AndroidManifest.xml as detailed below but get an exception that indicates I need the permissions that I have.  Not surprisingly, the scanner call back is never invoked.

```
W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
          java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results.  I'm not sure why the exception is thrown but I certianly DON'T get scan call backs.


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />


ScanCallback btScanCallback = new ScanCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result)
    {
        BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Found BLE device: " + btDevice.getName());


        // Remove the device from the scanner select view if its there already
        for( int i=0; i<btDeviceNameList.size(); i++)
        {
            String aDevice = btDeviceNameList.get(i);

            if(aDevice.equalsIgnoreCase(btDevice.getName()))
            {
                btDeviceNameList.remove(i);
                btDeviceList.remove(i);
                break;
            }
       }

        // Add the device to the scanner select view
        btDeviceList.add(btDevice);
        btDeviceNameList.add(btDevice.getName());

        btListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode)
    {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "BT scan error: " + errorCode);
    }
};
```

Comment: Stating that your app wants to use a permission is not the same things as your app actually _having_ that permission. Which Android version are you testing on, and which Android version are you targeting? If the answer for both is >=Marshmallow, where is your code for requesting the permission?

Comment: SDK is 8.1 Oreo and target is 6.0 Marshmallow.  I don't request permissions.

Comment: Well, since Marshmallow you need to request permissions at runtime. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: It looks like permissions aren’t required if specific services are requested.  I’m looking for a known scanner type.  Working on that and we’ll see how it goes.

Comment: @zappullae good luck. You cannot get scan results without having requested the permission. Btw the location services also need to be enabled.

Comment: I hate to say it but u r right.  See below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using android 6.0 or greater than that. The app has to request location permission at running time. After getting Bluetooth Adapter, just insert one line of code as below to request location permission. When the app runs, a dialog will be showed to ask whether the users agree to shared their location.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001);
```

Comment: I did that and it worked fine.  Im curious why we have to ask for location permissions to use BLE.  I’m writing a very non intrusive app trying not to get any personal info from the device such as location that I don’t need.

Comment: @zappullae In Marshmallow these dangerous permissions should be granted at run time and the normal permissions are granted automatically. For Lollipop (API level 22) or lower android versions the permissions specified in manifest are granted at installation.
I read it from this link: https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html

Comment: @zappullae please mark my answer if my answer has solved your problem

Comment: Marked.  At this point my best guess is location privs might be need to receive BLE data because the signal is analyzed for proximity of the two devices to each other.

Comment: Make sure to activate the localisation and BLE into your Android OS setting!
Asking for permission doesn't toggle automatically the localisation in the OS